# RSpec -- Tests seeming to be getting stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

So I have a handful of tests. These have run in the past, but now when I run `rspec` it seemingly just hangs.

Any thoughts here or best approach to go about debugging to figure out why it's hanging?

UPDATE:

Looks like it's hanging on trying to load the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
```

UPDATE:

Noticed `rails c` is also hanging

Answer (score 0):

Could be another instance of rspec is still running somewhere:

[Why won't rspec run? Rspec just hangs after starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088355/why-wont-rspec-run-rspec-just-hangs-after-starting)

Answer (score -1):

Welp, so restarted my computer and set MySQL to boot up on start, and that solved the issue! Guessing it must have had something to do with, MySQL in some fashion or another